# How can I copy part of an iMessage message? - What prevents Apple and Google from offering this functionality?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, copy-paste, sms

Starting from iOS 10, Apple changed[1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258300/how-to-copy-part-of-a-text-ios10) the "tap and hold" gesture in Messages so that you cannot select just a couple of words from the messages to copy.

And, as far as I know, Google did the same with Android.

I don't believe that it was done to just introduce into messages "tapback" which uses the same long-tapping as text selection.

Is there any objective reason for consciously disabling text selection in Messages?

Are there legal or regulative reasons for disabling text selection in Messages?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking why apple did or didn't do something.

Comment: @JBis I'm, not asking about Apple, I'm asking about reasons which are not clear for me

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is an objective reason for consciously disabling text selection in messages. Possible there's even more than one.

The most obvious one is that it allows for introducing other features than text selection in messages by using the same touch gesture for those other features.

However it is not so that it is impossible to copy only part of a text message with iOS 10 and newer - it is just more complicated. You can copy part of a text message by tapping and holding on the message, select "More...", press the forward arrow, and then tap and hold on the text message to select as usual.

There are no legal or regulative requirements in the US or in Europe that explicitly requires Apple to not offer text selection in messages. There could however be a patent that prevents Apple from doing so without licensing.